# Test Condition for a Boost Function in c++

Tags: c++, boost

The boost function rowclicked refers to a pointer to a function that  returns a void and takes an integer as a parameter. I am trying to pass an IF condition for this pointer, basically saying if rowclicked gets activated,I wish to assign some values

```
boost::function<void(int)> rowClicked;
    userClass->getTable()- >rowClicked=boost::bind(&UserController::onCellTableclicked,this);
```

this is the If condition

```
    if(userClass->getTable()->rowClicked)
                      {
                          std::cout<<"Row Clicked";
                          m=i;n=j;

                      }
                }
```

What changes do I make so as to pass an IF condition for a boost function that has been binded already in the class constructor..

```
 userClass->getTable()->rowClicked=boost::bind(&UserController::onCellTableclicked,this);
```

Fullcode from one of the main cpp files
:

```
#include "UserController.h"

// needed to bind the boost function
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include "UserClass.h"

// needed for used classes
#include <SUIButton.h>
#include <SUIProgressBar.h>
#include <SUIDialog.h>
#include <SUILabel.h>
#include <SUIGraphicsView.h>
#include <SUITableWidget.h>

// needed for the timer
#include <SUITimer.h>

//needed for time
#include <SUITime.h>

//needed for date
#include <SUIDate.h>

//needed for date time
#include <SUIDateTime.h>

//void getMonth( int,UserClass*);
//int co=1;

 int cou=1;
 int m,n;
// needed for output
#include <iostream>

UserController::UserController(UserClass *userClass) :
    userClass(userClass), // assign the instance of userClass
    timer(SUI::Timer::createTimer()), // instantiate the timer
    timeTimer(SUI::Timer::createTimer()),
    time(SUI::Time::createTime()),
    date(SUI::Date::createDate())


{
    // bind the Button clicked callback
    userClass->getStartButton()->clicked = boost::bind(&UserController::onStartButtonClicked,this);
    userClass->getStopButton()->clicked = boost::bind(&UserController::onStopButtonClicked,this);

    // bind the ProgreimeoutssBar valueChanged callback
    userClass->getProgressBar()->progressChanged = boost::bind(&UserController::onProgressBarValueChanged,this);
    //std::cout<<userClass->getTable()->cellClicked;
    //std::cout<<row;

    userClass->getTable()->rowClicked=boost::bind(&UserController::onCellTableclicked,this);
    //std::cout
    userClass->getleftarrow()->clicked=boost::bind(&UserController::onLeftArrowClicked,this);
    userClass->getrightarrow()->clicked=boost::bind(&UserController::onRightArrowClicked,this);
   // userClass->getimvimage1()->getGraphicsScene()
    // setup the timer
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    timer->setInterval(100);

    timeTimer->setSingleShot(false);
    timeTimer->setInterval(1);

    // bind the Timer timeout callback
    timer->timeout = boost::bind(&UserController::onTimerTimeout,this);
    timeTimer->timeout = boost::bind(&UserController::onTimeTimerTimeout,this);

    //start the time
    time->start();
    //initialise date
    date->currentDate();
    userClass->getDateLabel()->setText(date->toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    date->setDate(date->getYear(),date->getMonth(),1);
    //std::cout<<co;

   // std::cout<<date->getDayOfWeek();

    //dislay month on calendar label
    int mon=date->getMonth();
    //enum month={"January"=1,"February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
    switch(mon)
    {
   case 1: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("January");break;
   case 2: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("February");break;
   case 3: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("March");break;
   case 4: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("April");break;
   case 5: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("May");break;
   case 6: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("June");break;
   case 7: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("July");break;
   case 8: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("August");break;
   case 9: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("September");break;
   case 10: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("October");break;
   case 11: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("November");break;
   case 12: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("December");break;
    }
    //int mo=date->getMonth();
    //getMonth(mo);
    userClass->getyearlabel()->setText(std::to_string(date->getYear()));
    int c=date->getDayOfWeek();
            int count=1;

            int i=1;

            for(int j=c;j<=6;j++)
                {

                 userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j,std::to_string(count));
                 count++;
               }

               for (int i=2;i<=6;i++)
                {
                for(int j=0;j<=6 && count<=date->getDaysInMonth();j++)
                 {


                    userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j,std::to_string(count));
                    count++;

                    if(count<=date->getDaysInMonth())
                    continue;
                    else break;
                     /* if(userClass->getTable()->rowClicked)
                      {
                          std::cout<<"Row Clicked";
                          m=i;n=j;

                      }*/
                }
                }
    //userClass->getimvimage1()->getGraphicsScene(GraphicsScene)
    //show the dialog
    userClass->getDialog()->show();
    userClass->getStopButton()->setEnabled(false);

}

UserController::~UserController()
{
   delete userClass;
}


void UserController::onStopButtonClicked() {
    std::cout << "Stop clicked" << std::endl;

    // stop the timers
    timer->stop();
    timeTimer->stop();

    // enable/disable the buttons
    userClass->getStopButton()->setEnabled(false);
    userClass->getStartButton()->setEnabled(true);
}

void UserController::onProgressBarValueChanged() {
    // spam output when the ProgressBar value changed
    std::cout << "ProgressBar value changed to: " << userClass->getProgressBar()->getValue() << std::endl;
}

void UserController::onTimerTimeout() {
    // when the timer timed out increase the value of the ProgressBar with 1
    userClass->getProgressBar()->setValue(userClass->getProgressBar()->getValue() + 1);


    // if the ProgressBar value is smaller than 75 restart the timer
        if (userClass->getProgressBar()->getValue() < 75)
        timer->start();


}

void UserController::onTimeTimerTimeout() {
    // every interval, add 1 msec
    time->addMSecs(1);

    timer->setSingleShot(true);

    // set the label text
    userClass->getTimeLabel()->setText(time->toString("HH:mm:ss.zzz"));


}

void UserController::onStartButtonClicked() {

    // on clicked start the timer
    std::cout << "Start clicked" << std::endl;
    timer->start();
    timeTimer->start();
    // restart the time to current time
    time->restart();

    // enable/disable the buttonsuserClass->getTimeLabel()->setText(time->toString("HH:mm:ss.zzz"));
    userClass->getStopButton()->setEnabled(true);
    userClass->getStartButton()->setEnabled(false);
}



void UserController::onLeftArrowClicked()
{
    std::cout<<"Left Arrow"<<std::endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=6;j++)
        {
            userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j," ");
        }
    }

   int mo=date->getMonth()-1;
   int year=date->getYear();
   if(mo==0)
   {
    year=date->getYear()-1;
    mo=12;
   }
   date->setDate(year,mo,1);
   //std::cout<<mo<<std::endl;
   int c=date->getDayOfWeek();
           int count=1;

           int i=1;

           for(int j=c;j<=6;j++)
               {

                userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j,std::to_string(count));
                count++;
              }

              for (int i=2;i<=6;i++)
               {

               for(int j=0;j<=6 && count<=date->getDaysInMonth();j++)
                {


                   userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j,std::to_string(count));
                   count++;

                   if(count<=date->getDaysInMonth())
                   continue;
                   else break;
               }

               }
              switch(mo)
              {
              case 1: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("January");break;
              case 2: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("February");break;
              case 3: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("March");break;
              case 4: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("April");break;
              case 5: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("May");break;
              case 6: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("June");break;
              case 7: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("July");break;
              case 8: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("August");break;
              case 9: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("September");break;
              case 10: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("October");break;
              case 11: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("November");break;
              case 12: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("December");break;
              }
  userClass->getyearlabel()->setText(std::to_string(date->getYear()));
}


void UserController::onRightArrowClicked()
{
    std::cout<<"Right Arrow"<<std::endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=6;j++)
        {
            userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j," ");
        }
    }

   int mo=date->getMonth()+1;
   int year=date->getYear();
   if(mo==13)
   {
    year=date->getYear()+1;
    mo=1;
   }
   date->setDate(year,mo,1);
   date->setDate(date->getYear(),mo,1);
   int c=date->getDayOfWeek();
           int count=1;

           int i=1;

           for(int j=c;j<=6;j++)
               {

                userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j,std::to_string(count));
                count++;
              }

              for (int i=2;i<=6;i++)
               {

               for(int j=0;j<=6 && count<=date->getDaysInMonth();j++)
                {


                   userClass->getTable()->setItemText(i,j,std::to_string(count));
                   count++;

                   if(count<=date->getDaysInMonth())
                   continue;
                   else break;
               }

               }
              switch(mo)
              {
              case 1: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("January");break;
              case 2: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("February");break;
              case 3: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("March");break;
              case 4: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("April");break;
              case 5: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("May");break;
              case 6: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("June");break;
              case 7: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("July");break;
              case 8: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("August");break;
              case 9: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("September");break;
              case 10: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("October");break;
              case 11: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("November");break;
              case 12: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText("December");break;
              }
              userClass->getyearlabel()->setText(std::to_string(date->getYear()));
            }




/*void getMonth( int mon,UserClass *userClass)
{
    switch(mon)
    {
   case 1: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("January"));break;
   case 2: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("February"));break;
   case 3: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("March"));break;
   case 4: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("April"));break;
   case 5: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("May"));break;
   case 6: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("June"));break;
   case 7: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("July"));break;
   case 8: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("August"));break;
   case 9: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("September"));break;
   case 10: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("October"));break;
   case 11: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("November"));break;
   case 12: userClass->getCalendarLabel()->setText(date->toString("December"));break;
    }
}*/

void UserController::onCellTableclicked() {

   //date->currentDate();
   //std::cout<<(userClass->getTable()->isEnabled());

//   std::cout<<"Just Print:"<<cou<<std::endl;
 //  cou++;
    //  userClass->getTable()->clearFocus();
   // userClass->getTable()->getCellID(int row, int col);
   // int day=userClass->getTable()->getItemText(row,col);
    //userClass->getTable()->toBaseWidget(this)->getWidget()->setText("Cl");
    //ObjectFactory::getInstance()->toBaseWidget(this)->getWidget()->hasFocus();
   // getWidget()->currentIndex().row()
    //std::cout<<userClass->getTable()->rowClicked();
   //std::string day=userClass->getTable()->getItemText(m,n);
    userClass->getTable()->
   //userClass->getTable()->currentIndex().row();

   //std::cout<<getWidget()->currentIndex().row();
   //date->setDate(1991,1,std::atoi(day.c_str()));

   //userClass->getDateLabel()->setText(date->toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
   //userClass->getTable()->getWidget()->setText("Cl");
}
```

Comment: Without some more details, it's hard to say what's going on. For one, `rowClicked` is a callable, so `if (userClass->getTable()->rowClicked)` is malformed (it's a function that should be called with an integer). For another, it looks like you're doing some kind of observer pattern, where `rowClicked` is actually a callback that should be registered to be automatically called on some event (like a "row" being clicked, so you'll know for sure that your condition is true)

Comment: @AndyG so there is no way to associate a check condition for this boost function? I want another event to happen when this row has been clicked (boost function)  but i want to return values (variables) from that initial event . I will post the full code .Thanks again for the help.

Comment: So you want to chain callbacks. When a row is clicked, the rowClicked callback happens. During the rowClicked callback, you can try to trigger another event. Perhaps the `rowClicked` callback is a member function on a class, and that class has its own observers. When the `rowClicked` is called, those observers can be notified (that is, have their callbacks called). It could end up being too much indirection. Why wouldn't the other listeners subscribe to the original `rowClicked` event? Some kind of order guarantee on notification?

Comment: @AndyG It's like there is this for loop inside the constructor,with which I want to trigger a boost event(clicking of a row) because I have to return some values from this for-loop to another function outside ,so as to display those values.In the code above, in the constructor  there is an if condition that has been commented
I want these i and J values in another function.How do I go about it?

Comment: Can anyone help me out please?